# How to differentiate Incoming call and Originated Call in Asterisk.NET NewState Event

Tags: c#, winforms, asterisk, asteriskami

I am developing a C#.NET Windows Application using Asterisk.NET Library.
In my application NewState Event is triggered even when I originate the call (when it rings the source).
I want only incoming calls to be shown as "Somebody is calling". Now it shows even for self-ringing calls (when originating),,, 
How can I check and avoid Originated calls from Newstate Event. Please Help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way:

1) create originate with

```
Channel: Local/1234@dialout
```

and

```
Set: id=1
Set: otherinfo="nice call"
```

2) create dialplan like this

```
[dialout]
exten =>_X.,1,UserEvent(CatchMe,number: ${EXTEN}, db_id: ${id}, otherinfo: ${otherinfo})
exten =>_X.,2,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@outtrunk,,)
```

Same will work for inbound!!!

But also you can check other events, not NewState(which is VERY common).